# Amenable groups and action

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, amenability

It is known that if a group $G$ acts amenably on a set $X$ and the stabilizer of every point in $X$ is amenable, then $G$ itself is amenable.

Is there any elementary proof of this fact?

Thanks!

Comment: Which definition of amenable group are you using?